# Which one is correct : 'does it worth all the trouble ?' or 'is it worth all the trouble ?'

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, do-support

I am currently confused between the use of these two:

> Does it worth all the trouble?

or

> Is it worth all the trouble?

Can some one suggest which one is correct?

Comment: If we ask "Does it {x}?", what part of speech is "{x}"? Is it an adjective or a verb?

Comment: verb,  i suppose.

Comment: Is there a verb, **worth**, in contemporary English?

Comment: While option 2 is correct, it is possible to begin the question with *Does* by inserting a phrase, such as: *Does it SEEM TO BE worth all the trouble?* or *Does it MAKE THE JOB worth all the trouble?*

Comment: Remembering this little phrase might be helpful: *It's worth it* (NOT *\*It worths it*.)

Comment: @TRomano, _worth_ can be a verb in other languages (_valoir_ in French for example). That may be a source of confusion.

Comment: One might also say "Does it merit all the trouble?", where "merit" is a verb.

Comment: @Dangph: The goal is to teach the learner how to build on their knowledge, whatever the source of their confusion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Worth* may be a noun or an adjective, but not a verb. In your context it is a predicate adjective, almost invariably employed with *BE*:

> This house is worth one million dollars.
>   It is worth the trouble.

Consequently, you cannot use *DO* here--there's no verb to act as its complement.

Comment: Good explanation. Worth noting that many other European languages have verbs meaning "to be worth": *valer* (es, pt), *valoir* (fr). I can't think of non-Romance examples right now. I don't know as much about non-European ones, but it wouldn't surprise me if there are many examples there too.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive:  "Does it *merit* all the trouble?"

Answer (score 7):

The common idiomatic phrase is "Is it worth X?" or even the seemingly [tautological](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/tautologies) "Is it worth it?"  In this case you have to figure out the meaning of the pronouns from context. For example:

> Buying a home can be a difficult, frustrating, and ultimately expensive process -- plus, afterwards, there are all the headaches the comes with home ownership.  ***Is it worth all that trouble?***
>
> Joining the military is a serious commitment that should not be taken lightly.  Before you let yourself be pressured into enlisting, you should ask yourself, ***"Is it worth it?"***

As others have pointed out, "worth" is not a verb and so you can't ask "Does it worth it?"  However can you use the standard "to be" verb to say things like:

> Does it seem like it *would be worth* the trouble?
>
> Does it look like a good investment that *is worth* the cost?

Comment: The tautological version would be "Is it worth itself?" It's perfectly normal to have pronouns refer to different things in the same sentence: "John went to the shopkeeper. He gave him five dollars."

Comment: @DavidRicherby  which is why I said "seemingly tautological".  Yes, I know it's not an actual tautology.